# electron-react-boilerplate :sub window on clicking a button

Tags: reactjs, electron

> i have a doubt that how the reactjs file can be loaded into a new window on
>   clicking a button in electron-react-boilerplate.

```
const handleVideoCall=()=>{
    const remote=require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow=remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      height: 600,
      width: 800,
    });

    win.loadFile(fileName);
  }
```

> handleVideoCall is the method which is called on clicking the button.
>   FileName is the reactjs file that i needed to open. 
>   As there is no documentation from react-electron-boilerplate i was stuck with this. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: what's your question? Do you want a line-by-line explanation about this exact code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i got the answer i think that this will be helpful for lot of peoples as there are no documentation for electron-react-boilerplate.
Make the nodeIntegration to true or preload js.

```
const handleVideoCallNew = async number => {
    const remote=require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow=remote.BrowserWindow;
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      height: 600,
      width: 800,
      frame:false,
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
    }
    });
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app.html#/login`);


  }
```

And on the router file

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

By using this code we can open the reactjs file and route to login. The app.html is main file which is loaded in main.dev.js in electron-react-boilerplate code. The hashing is simplest method to open the reactjs file.
   As the loadURL in electron only loads urls and htmls files we can't open js files. **So open the main app.html and hash using routes**.

Comment: That's the right answer, we just need to make sure to include the `<Route ...` in the right order: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2402#issuecomment-606444885

Answer (score 4):

Just create a react videoCall Component then create  a window and  load a url with query params like this,

```html
   const videoCallWidow = new BrowserWindow({
       height: 600,
        width: 800,     
      webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        webSecurity: false,
      },
    })
    

    videoCallWidow.loadURL(
       url.format({
            pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
            protocol: 'file:',
            slashes: true,
            query: {
              page: 'videoCall',
            },
          })
    )
```

after that, In your index.js file you will get query params so on that you can put a condition to load videoCall Component or app component .

```html
ReactDOM.render(
  locationPath === 'videoCall' ? <videoCallComponent /> : <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: what the url.format? Can you please share a complete example of what is getting done above?